# Is this hadith about remedies of every disease sahih?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, reference-request

The hadith:

> It was narrated that Abu’d-Darda’ said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah has sent down the disease and the remedy, and He has created a remedy for every disease, so seek treatment (of illness) but do not treat (illness) with anything that is haraam.”  Narrated by Abu Dawood, 3874;

[Islamqa](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/170208) says:

> It is classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.

But 
[Sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/20) says :

> Da'if (Al-Albani)

I'm confused. Plz try answer with reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hadith is basically correct in its meaning, similar authentic reports may be found elsewhere, for example:

> #### ما أنزل الله داء إلا أنزل له شفاء
>
> There is no disease that Allah has created, except that He also has created its treatment.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/76/1)</sup>

> #### إن الله لم يجعل شفاءكم فيما حرم عليكم
>
> Allah has not put your cure in what he has made unlawful to you.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari (Mu‘allaq)](https://archive.org/stream/SahihBukhariarabic-English9VolumesPublishedByDarussalam/SahihAl-bukhariVol.7-Ahadith5063-5969#page/n295/mode/2up), [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/5716#p1), [Sahih Ibn Hibban](https://shamela.ws/book/1729/2068), [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/9115)</sup>

Al-Albaani graded a similarly worded hadith as Saheeh in [al-Silsilah al-Saheehah (1633)](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/2368). However he graded the one in Sunan Abi Dawood as Da'if in [Da'if Sunan Abi Dawood](https://archive.org/stream/WAQssunnd/dsunnd#page/n312/mode/2up). I was not able to find it in [Saheeh Abi Dawood](https://archive.org/stream/WAQssunnd/ssunnd2#page/n464/mode/2up).

Comment: Regarding the second hadith,  my questions is, Is it the words of Prophet Muhammad (SAW )?  [Islam Q&A][https://islamqa.info/en/answers/11941/using-medicines-manufactured-from-animal-products] stated like this : "The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Allaah does not put your cure in that which He has forbidden to you.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari in his Saheeh, in a mu’allaq report from Ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him), in Kitaab al-Ashribah)." They said that this is the words of Prophet Muhammad (SAW). Is it correct ?

Comment: @RafidAbrar Yes, the Marfoo' hadith exists in [Sahih Ibn Hibban](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/2068), [Mu'jam al-Kabir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/24252#p1), [Sunan al-Kubra al-Bayhaqi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33024/34669#p1) etc. SImilar ahadith include نهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن الدواء الخبيث in [Abi Dawud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/16) etc.

Comment: Would you plz cite the hadith which is classed as Sahih is Silsilah Al Sahih, 1633? The link, you've given, is in Arabic. So it's not possible for me to read it.

Comment: @RafidAbrar The hadith is إن الله خلق الداء والدواء، فتداووا، ولا تتداووا بحرام  , translated by [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13272/using-medicines-does-not-cancel-out-the-idea-of-putting-ones-trust-in-allaah) as "Allaah created the disease and the cure, so treat disease but do not treat it with anything that is haraam."

Answer (score 4):

Just as an addition to the given answer.

There are basically two reasons as to why scholars declared the hadith from Sunan abi Dawod as da'if: (I've add a transliteration/translation of the full narrator chain)

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبَادَةَ الْوَاسِطِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا يَزِيدُ بْنُ هَارُونَ، أَخْبَرَنَا **إِسْمَاعِيلُ بْنُ عَيَّاشٍ،** عَنْ ثَعْلَبَةَ بْنِ مُسْلِمٍ، عَنْ أَبِي عِمْرَانَ الأَنْصَارِيِّ، عَنْ أُمِّ الدَّرْدَاءِ، عَنْ أَبِي الدَّرْدَاءِ، قَالَ
>   We narrated from Muhammad ibn 'Abadah al-Wasiti who narrated it from Yazid ibn Harun who was informed by **Ismai'l ibn 'Ayyach** from Tha'alabah ibn Muslim from abu 'Imran al-Ansari from Umm al-Darda' Narrated Abu al-Darda:
>
> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ أَنْزَلَ الدَّاءَ وَالدَّوَاءَ وَجَعَلَ لِكُلِّ دَاءٍ دَوَاءً فَتَدَاوَوْا **وَلاَ تَدَاوَوْا بِحَرَامٍ** ‏"‏ ‏.
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Allah has sent down both the disease and the cure, and He has appointed a cure for every disease, so treat yourselves medically, **but use nothing unlawful**. ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/20) or [here](http://qaalarasulallah.com/hadithView.php?ID=23875))

1. The first is the addition "but use nothing unlawful" which doesn't appear in the most reliable hadith collections (the two sahihs) and most other hadith sources.
2. And the narrator Ismai'l ibn Ayyach who is a a-Shaam narrator and he is known for some weaknesses especially in his narrations from Hijaazi teachers. Al-Mundhiri and al-Manaawi (see for example [here](https://library.islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=3426&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=304&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) in Fayd al-Qadir فيض القدير ) and other early scholars said he is discussed (meaning that he might be upright, but not in all his narrations). al-Shawakani says in this case he is narrating from a Shaami teacher and wondered why others considered it as weak (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1118&idfrom=2632&idto=2633&flag=0&bk_no=47&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) in Arabic in Nail al-Awtaar نيل الأوطار ). Al-Albani however say that the issue is rather his teacher Tha'alabah ibn Muslim.

Al-Albani commented this hadith as follows (foot note) in his [التعليقات الرضية على الروضة الندية](https://ia802905.us.archive.org/3/items/WAQ39689/trdia3.pdf)  Vol3 page 154:

> الحديث صحيح – من حيث معناه – لشواهده
>   The hadith is sane (sahih) in meaning due to the witnessing narrations

This means there are many narrations that actually support the meaning for example using alcohol as a remedy is something declared as prohibited in [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/15) sahih hadith.